# how to create a struct/model in golang with dynamic/arbitrary fields

Tags: go, struct, interface, mapping

Is it possible to create a struct with dynamic/arbitrary fields and values?

My app will receive request with JSON body:

```
{
"Details": {
  "Id": “123”,
 },
"Event": {
  "Event": "Event",
 },
“RequestValues”: [
  {
    “Name": "Name1",
    "Value": "Val1"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Name2",
    "Value": 2
  },
  {
    "Name": “Foo”,
    "Value": true
  }
    ]
  }
```

This will be unmarshalled to my model 'Request':

```
type Request struct {
    Details         Details          `json:"Details"`
    Event           Event            `json:"Event"`
    RequestValues []RequestValues    `json:"RequestValues"`
}

type Details struct {
    Id     string `json:"Id"`
}

type Event struct {
    Event      string `json:"Event"`
}

type RequestValues struct {
    Name  string `json:"Name"`
    Value string `json:"Value"`
}
```

I have to re-map model 'Request' to a new model 'Event' with arbitrary fields in "Values". After marshalling new re- mapped model 'Event' I should get this JSON output that corresponds to the request:

```
{
"Event": "Event"
"Values": {
  “Id": "123",      <= non arbitrary mapping from Request.Detail.Id
  "Name1": "Val1",  <= arbitrary 
  "Name2": 2,       <= arbitrary
  “Foo”: true       <= arbitrary
}
```

}

Arbitrary values will be mapped from "RequestValues". Names of those fields should be the values of Request.RequestValues.Name and their values should be the values of Request.RequestValues.Value

Here is my 'Event' model:

```
type Event struct {
    Event             string `json:"Event"`
    Values            Values `json:"Values"`
}

type Values struct{
    Id      string  `json:"Id"`
}
```

Comment: Use a `map[string]interface{}` if the keys are not known at compile time.

Comment: thanks Peter, I have tried that but I have been struggling with how to exactly implement map[string]interface{} , please could you give an example of how would you do it for that exact scenario?

Comment: No, because you haven't provided any code to start with. It should be obvious, though: change whatever type the Values field is now to `map[string]interface{}`.

Comment: Perhaps it's obvious once you know how to do it. @MarcinKulik you'll get better responses to people if you show some things you've tried - even if wrong. The answerer can help you understand what you got wrong.

Comment: Thank you guys, I have had attempt at a better description of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, here's a JSON-valid copy of your JSON:

```json
{
    "Details": {
        "Id": "123"
    },
    "Event": {
        "Event": "Event"
    },
    "RequestValues": [
        {
            "RequestValueName": "Name1",
            "RequestValue": "Val1"
        },
        {
            "RequestValueName": "Name2",
            "RequestValue": 2
        },
        {
            "RequestValueName": "Foo",
            "RequestValue": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Start by creating a `type Input struct{}` to describe the JSON that you're looking to parse, and a `type Output struct{}` for the JSON that you're looking to generate, and write a little code to convert from one to the other. You don't have to add all of the fields right away - you can start with just `Event` for example and add more until you've got them all.

I've done this in https://play.golang.org/p/PvpKnFMrJjN to show you, but I would recommend having only a quick read of it before trying to recreate it yourself.

A useful tool to convert JSON into Go structs is https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/ but it will trip on `RequestValue` in your example which has several data types (and is therefore where we use `interface{}`).

Comment: thank you @icio, your example in play.golang.org has worked for me, Values should be map[string]interface{} rather than a struct

Answer (score 0):

I thing that you can use map like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Event struct {
    event  string
    values map[string]string
}

func main() {
    eventVar := Event{event: "event", values: map[string]string{}}
    eventVar.values["Id"] = "12345"
    eventVar.values["vale1"] = "value"
    fmt.Println(eventVar)
}
```

You just need to validate somehow that the id it's in there, this if you need values in the same level.

I hope this works for you.